# Machine Learning: How Do You Instruct Your Model To Recognize a Non-existent Dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I used the code below to train my model.

```
# Data Preparation
objDataset = pd.read_csv('objdbase.csv')
X = objDataset.drop(columns=['Substance'])
y = objDataset['Substance']

# Prediction
def predicts(fingerprint):
    models = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    models.fit(X, y)
    predictions = models.predict([fingerprint])
    print(f'The substance is likely {predictions}')
```

I want the model, if it receives a dataset that is not among the ones in the database, to say something like: "Target not recognized". How do I modify the algorithm to be able to perform that?

Answer (score 0):

The prediction will give you the probability of a certain result.
A model is not a method to check if something exists or not